# Illegal attempt to create connection from another pool:

Tags: java, datasource, weblogic-10.x

I have to extend one of the queries, to join with the table in another database, and possibly another server (linked).
Here are some domain facts, I can't change:

```
- Weblogic 10 used.  EJB2 on the Java side

 - Database driver is Non-XA.  And we can't change that
 - Both of the data sources are set as "Emulate 2 phase commit" transaction 
   option
```

-    Query that is used is not directly in the business method called by the client, but somewhere in a private method, that is called at some point in the execution.

I am getting the following

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been created in this tx 
 context 
 for pool named dataSourceA.datasource. Illegal attempt to create 
 connection from another pool: dataSourceB.datasource
```

I only need to get the Database name and database host from the data source.
Exceptions comes, when I try to make connection to the data source dataSourceB. 
Is there any way to get its properties without making a connection?  Just to get String properties, database name and host?

Comment: If your datasource is set to use "One Phase Commit" option , change it to "Emulate Two Phase Commit"

Comment: Actually, both of the data sources are set as Emulate Two Phase Commit